# Binary File Read Performance C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, io, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read large binary LAS file like this

```
struct format
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
    short red;
    short green;
    short blue;
    short alpha;
    unsigned long intensity
    // etc.
}

std::ifstream stream;
Point3 GetPoint()
{
    format f;
    stream.seekg(offset);
    offset += sizeof(format);
    stream.Read((char *)f, sizeof(format));
    return Point3(f.X, f.Y, f.Z);
}
```

In main function:

```
Point3* points = new Point3[count]
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    points[i] = GetPoint();
```

This operation takes about 116 seconds with 18million point records. But in a LAS Tool it takes nearly 15 seconds to read and start visualization of the same data.

How it can be fast 7 times then mine's? Is multithreading or something else? If my reading function is not well, how it can be worser 7 times then it?

I have some information about memory mapped files. It is very fast to load whole file to the memory but LAS files can be more then 15GBs which is oversized of my memory size so it will be load to virtual memory. Even I have enough memory I must read the memory mapped file with a loop too.

Can someone give me a help about this situation?

Comment: You only need to map part of the file, not all of it.

Comment: Are you sure `stream.Read((char *)f, sizeof(format))` will always give you desired results? I think the members in `format` don't have to be allocated with continues memory (definitely increasing, but no guarantee to be adjacent)

Comment: If you don't use memory map, use large arrays to read in large amount of records.  The more records read, the more efficient the operation is.  For each read operation, the drive must locate the start or position within the file, then read the sequential bytes.  Locating the file position on the drive takes time as well as waiting for the drive to achieve correct speed.

Comment: @YZ.learner format is not in legal order and not contains ol the members. In original 6 structures contain everything of a LAS file specific point data formats and yes I'm sure it is adjacent with usage of right point data format. Thanks for warning

Answer (score 2):

Since the file is being read sequentially, why the call seekg?
Try removing seekg.

Some other things you can try:

- Read the file by blocks (32K) and pass these to another thread (look for consumer/producer pattern). The second thread (the consumer) can parse the blocks and fill the points array while the first thread (the producer) is waiting for I/O.
- If Point3 defines a constructor, use a vector<> instead this way you won't have to create 'count' Point3 objects when you create the array.

Also, how do you know that the LAS tool waits for the entire file to be read before rendering? Is it possible that it starts the rendering before the file is completely read in?

Comment: Actually it was reading specific index, you are right no need to use it now. Bu I think this will not make a lot change? Am I false?

Comment: Wow, I am surprised. Now it takes about 62 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü If the answer solves your problem, you should definitely accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @0x499602D2: It is a very useful tip but not the correct answer.

Comment: The Point3 array I gave in the example is actualy a vertex array, I load it with point3 coordinates and I use CreateVertexBuffer function of directx. So it is not useful to use std::vector and I dont need to acces this array's members.

I am not completely sure that the tool is not showing all the data but tried again now and see yes it seems it loads all the data before display. It is using a file to output something while it is doing these things. This tool is Pointools View 1.8 Pro. On the other hand, LASTools is showing data while loading but it is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your implementation `ifstream` is notoriously slow. On MS compilers, for example, it relies on `<cstdio>` for buffering. What this means is, it calls into 'c' functions for every byte to be read.

Also, are you sure you can just copy memory into your structure? Have you taken padding into account?

Like your question states, memory mapped files are a lot faster. You don't need to map the whole file, you can map a small part of it. Usually, mapping a part the same size as the systems page size is adequate.

look into `mmap`.

Comment: I'm going to do a lot more search about mmap and return as soon as possible.